# return object of different subclass from superclass initialize method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, initialization, return

So I have multiple subclasses of Thing, represented here as ThingA and ThingB.
A few things should be taken for granted here:

- a Thing is never created directly - i.e `Thing.new`
- a ThingA must pass a test when initialized, otherwise it should be a ThingB
- a ThingB can safely be assumed to be a ThingB

Here is a sketch of my hierarchy:

```
class Thing
  def initialize( var = 'yes' )
    @var = var    
    if !self.verify?
      ThingB.new( var )
    elsif self.class != ThingB
      #code for ThingA
      @Aness = 'huge' 
    end
    #code for ThingA & ThingB
    puts 'END'
  end

  def verify?
    if self.class == ThingA
      @var == 'yes'
    else
      true
    end
  end
end

class ThingA < Thing
end

class ThingB < Thing
end
```

My question is, how can I get

```
ThingA.new( 'no' )
```

to return a `ThingB` instead?

This is really annoying me, because I had this working with *very* similar code, but somehow I lost the desired functionality.  With the above, I get the following output:

```
[21] pry(main)> ThingA.new
END
=> #<ThingA:0x60bd4b0 @Aness="huge", @var="yes">
#this is fine
[22] pry(main)> ThingB.new
END
=> #<ThingB:0x53ba6b8 @var="yes">
#this also
[23] pry(main)> ThingA.new( 'no' )
END
END
=> #<ThingA:0x64bec40 @var="no">
#this should be ThingB
```

'END' prints twice, implying that a ThingB was initialized, but it does not get returned in lieu of the original ThingA.  Instead I have a ThingA with no Aness.

As mentioned, I had extremely similar code that functioned as wanted, without using `throw` or anything - which I somehow broke.

Using `return` only stops the first initialize from ending, and still returns the original object.

Comment: I can't imagine why this would ever be a good idea. If you need to pass logic to something to get different classes, why not just make a utility class that does only that?

Comment: Whether the class is correct or not is dependent on an external verification done on a file that the object has been created to represent.  Therefore it is impossible to know before the object is initialized whether the correct class is being used - the user may not even know themselves.

Comment: You would have to create something like a Factory method to implement this logic and return the correct instance. But I agree with @JimmyBaker when he says this is not a good idea. Maybe you should extract this logic for the creation to a higher level method and invoke the creation of the correct object after this logic be applied.

Comment: I should note this is intended for use in a Ruby repl, so it would be preferable that the verification is done when trying to initialize an Object of desired subclass.  If you have a better way to acheive my goal, please draft it.

Comment: So you're trying to do what here?  Initialize an object, then test if it's the right object.  If it's the wrong object, do what?  Get a different object?  I'd agree with Ed, it sounds like you want a Factory here.

Comment: In a repl environment, i'm trying to verify an arbitrary file when an object is created to represent it.  The user may presume the file fits a particular subclass, however if the file cannot be verified it is actually a different subclass.  A user may also want to choose a third subclass which needs no verification, so initializing them by name would be preferred.  I wanted to use Ruby syntax for uniformity since users may be inexperienced, but perhaps I should just use my own constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not necessarily advocating that this is the *correct* way to design your system, but there's two reasons that what you've written doesn't work as you intended it.

First, even in a 'simple' case, the above would never result in the return value being a ThingB; the last line of your `initialize` method is a `puts` call, and `puts` always has a return value of `nil`, so in the simple case of a 'normal' method, your return value still wouldn't be a ThingB instance, it'd be `nil`.

But, as you say,

> Using `return` only stops the first initialize from ending, and still returns the original object.

I'm assuming you mean using an explicit `return` in the initialize method, like this hypothetical code:

```
class Thing
  def initialize( var = 'yes' )
    @var = var    
    if !self.verify?
      return ThingB.new( var ) # explicit return
    elsif self.class != ThingB
      #code for ThingA
      @Aness = 'huge' 
    end
    #code for ThingA & ThingB
    puts 'END'
  end

  def verify?
    if self.class == ThingA
      @var == 'yes'
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

So why *doesn't* that work? The answer is subtle, but ultimately simple, and pretty key to understanding Ruby (I think): you're not calling `initialize` in your code, you're calling `new`. New can't just return whatever initialize returns, because then your original class definition (without an explicit return) would have made ThingA.new return `nil`![*]

The way `new` actually works is more like this:

```
class Thing
  def self.new(*args)
    obj = self.allocate
    obj.initialize(*args) # sort of; initialize is private
    return obj
  end
end
```

You'll note that the return value of initialize is completely ignored; that's a good thing, if it weren't we'd have to have every initializer tediously return `self`, and we'd get errors every time we forgot.

So, if you want `ThingA.new` to return an instance of `ThingB`, you don't need to modify `ThingA#initialize`, you need to modify `ThingA.new`:

```
class Thing
end

class ThingA < Thing
  def self.verify?(var)
    var == 'yes'
  end

  def self.new(var = 'yes')
    if self.verify?(var)
      super
    else
      ThingB.new(var)
    end
  end

  def initialize(var)
    @Aness = 'huge'
  end
end

class ThingB < Thing
end
```

I should stress that this is not necessarily a wise thing to do with your code. But I *do* think knowing how to do it, and why it works, is important to understanding Ruby.

---

[*]: Again, not because it lacks an explicit return, but because it implicitly returns the value of the last evaluated expression, which is `puts 'END'`, and `puts` always returns `nil`.

Comment: thank you for this comprehensive explanation.  Could you please elaborate or point me in the direction as to why this smells?  I'm self taught working my way into oop/Ruby from writing batch files, so I have no knowledge of system design.  Could defining new be acceptable in a repl interface where the user may have limited experience, the intended class is known, but not whether it is correct for the external file the object is referencing?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with redefining new in the right circumstances, I'm just not sure these are the right circumstances. Your proposed use case is a pretty unusual one, and hypothetically I can see where you're coming from in wanting to keep things as simple as possible for the end user. However, there are two issues: First of all, I can't really recommend a good structure for accomplishing what you want without knowing more about your problem domain - how are a ThingA and a ThingB similar/different, does a Thing that is not a ThingA or ThingB, but just a Thing, ever make sense...

Comment: ... etc. Second, if you are going to break a 'rule' (which, as I said, you _can_ do in the right circumstances), you want your _own_ code, that does the breaking, to be extremely clean and well structured, so that it's always clear (at least to you) exactly what's going on, when the end user encounters a problem down the line and you have to figure out why it didn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ThingB
  def initialize(var = "yes")
    @var = var
    puts "END"
  end
end

class ThingA < ThingB
  def initialize(var = "yes")
    #code for ThingA
    @Aness = "huge"
    super
  end
  class <<self
    alias old_new new
    def new(var = "yes")
      verify?(var) ? ThingA.old_new(var) : ThingB.new(var)
    end
    def verify?(var)
      var == "yes"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for has been around for a while and is called the *Factory Pattern* (see Wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

"In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created."

When the class of the instance is not known before creation, *you should not be using a constructor to create it*.  You should instead be using another method that does the test and creates an instance of the appropriate class.

In a stable, strictly controlled class hierarchy, this method could be a class method on your `Thing` class:

```
class Thing
  def self.create
    if something
      Thing1.new
    else
      Thing2.new
    end
  end
end
```

This creates a dependency of the more general class on the more specific specializations of it, which in general is not a good idea, but if you're in total control of the subclasses may not be too bad.

If there is a problem with circular dependencies (e.g. Thing2 being used before it is defined), then you can create a minimal factory class or module after defining Thing, Thing1, and Thing2:

```
require 'thing'
require 'thing1'
require 'thing2'

class ThingFactory
  def self.create
    # ...same logic as before
  end
end
```

The other approach would be to create another method somewhere else (that is, in a different, unrelated class) to do the same thing.

---

In regard to your comment about this being intended for a REPL for use by novices, there *is* something you can do quite simply to accomplish this; you can create a Module containing a `new` method:

```
module Thing
  def self.new
    some_condition ? Thing1.new : Thing2.new
  end
end
```

In general programming, this is a *very* bad idea because it is very misleading to the developer using your code; `Thing` looks like a class that you're instantiating with a conventional `new` method, but it's not.

A better way would be to just require your users to understand that in this case they need to call `ThingFactory.create` rather than `ThingX.new`.

However, if you're *really* sure that hiding this distinction will not confuse and obstruct your users, this strategy might be acceptable in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was a useful explanation of a technique I was unaware of.  Why it is not suitable is because the interface is intended to be a Ruby repl, potentially for use by those with little/no coding experience - I would like ease of use and syntax uniformity to be paramount.  In addition the class 'intended' to be initialized may be known, but not whether the object ( specifically the external file it represents ) fits the class.  Do you have any suggestions for reading material/approaches in this area of system building?  Once again, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Please see the section I added to my answer.  To add emphasis, this approach is *only* suitable if there is absolutely no need for the caller to distinguish between the classes of returned objects. (I am skeptical.) Regarding reading materials, I suggest googling 'design patterns' and valuing especially highly anything written by Martin Fowler.